# How to add reboot button to Jailbreak Application in Theos

Tags: ios, button, jailbreak, reboot, theos

To make respring button, I can write code as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setTitle:@"Respring" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100,50,120,100);

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)buttonPushed:(id)sender

{
    system("killall -9 SpringBoard");
    return;

}
```

But to make reboot button, It doesn't seem to be able to do like this .

what code should I write?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
- (void)buttonPushed:(id)sender

{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] reboot];
    return;

}
```

I tried this in a sample project found [here](https://github.com/abart997/EasyRespring) and it worked. I replaced the template's call to

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] relaunchSpringBoard];
```

with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] reboot];
```